# Rails "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arguments

UPDATE2: Full error:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (3 for 2):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:426:in `form_for'
  client_side_validations (3.2.6) lib/client_side_validations/action_view/form_helper.rb:25:in `form_for'
  simple_form (3.0.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:22:in `block in simple_form_for'
  simple_form (3.0.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:41:in `with_simple_form_field_error_proc'
  simple_form (3.0.0) lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:21:in `simple_form_for'
  app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_devise_sessions_new_html_erb___3264503595341643731_70125077516440'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/tehras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:233:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:161:in `to_html'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:154:in `respond'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:147:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:330:in `respond_with'
  devise (3.2.1) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `new'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__3832680432418076242__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
  client_side_validations (3.2.6) lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1440453977638564550__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/tehras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/tehras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/tehras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

UPDATE: my login gets the same error, i think something is overriding my simple_form?

Here's my partial for the form, this was literally working 10 minutes ago and i didn't change anything.

```
<%= simple_form_for @cast do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification :message => "There is a problem with one or more fields" %>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button style="margin-bottom:5px" type="button" class="btn" id="3v3" onclick="ajax_match('3v3')">3 v 3
      </button>
      <button style="margin-bottom:5px" type="button" class="btn" id="5v5" onclick="ajax_match('5v5')">5 v 5
      </button>
    </div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :match_type, :id => "match_type" %>
    <div class="form-group" id="red_team" style="display: none;">
      <%= f.text_field :red_team, placeholder: "Red Team", id: "red_team_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
      <span id="red_team_error" style="display:none">*Must be 2 - 8 Characters Long </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="blue_team" style="display: none">
      <%= f.text_field :blue_team, placeholder: "Blue Team", id: "blue_team_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
      <span id="blue_team_error" style="display:none">*Must be 2 - 8 Characters Long </span>
    </div>
    <div class="from-group" id="tournament_name" style="display: none">
      <%= f.text_field :tournament_name, placeholder: "Tournament Name", id: "tournament_name_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
      <span id="tournament_name_error" style="display:none">*Must be 2 - 15 Characters Long </span>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="from-group" id="caster" style="display: none">
      <%= f.text_field :caster, placeholder: "Caster/Casters", id: "caster_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
      <span id="caster_error" style="display:none">*Must be 2 - 8 Characters Long </span>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="form-group" id="best_of" style="display: none">
      <button style="margin-bottom:5px" type="button" class="btn" id="bo1" onclick="ajax_bo('1')">BO1</button>
      <button style="margin-bottom:5px" type="button" class="btn" id="bo3" onclick="ajax_bo('3')">BO3</button>
      <button style="margin-bottom:5px" type="button" class="btn" id="bo5" onclick="ajax_bo('5')">BO5</button>
      <button style="margin-bottom:5px" type="button" class="btn" id="bo7" onclick="ajax_bo('7')">BO7</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="link1" style="display:none">
      <%= f.text_field :link, placeholder: "Game 1 Embedded Link", id: "link1_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="link2" style="display:none">
      <%= f.text_field :link2, placeholder: "Game 2 Embedded Link", id: "link2_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="link3" style="display:none">
      <%= f.text_field :link3, placeholder: "Game 3 Embedded Link", id: "link3_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="link4" style="display:none">
      <%= f.text_field :link4, placeholder: "Game 4 Embedded Link", id: "link4_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="link5" style="display:none">
      <%= f.text_field :link5, placeholder: "Game 5 Embedded Link", id: "link5_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="link6" style="display:none">
      <%= f.text_field :link6, placeholder: "Game 6 Embedded Link", id: "link6_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="link7" style="display:none">
      <%= f.text_field :link7, placeholder: "Game 7 Embedded Link", id: "link7_field", class: 'form-control', required: "required" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions" id="submit" style="display:none">
      <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-info' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :best_of, :id => 'best_of_hidden' %>

  </div>
</form>
<% end %>
```

This form is to create a new cast, which essentially is a post. 
Please helpp... this was working now it's not, the controller defines @cast = Cast.new.

Comment: Can you post the full error here?

Comment: I posted the full error. I think it's something with simple_form, it was working for me for days, and all of a sudden it stopped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure, but I think it might be ClientSideValidations. This is how `form_for` is declared in ActionView:

```
def form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
```

and this is how it is called in ClientSideValidations (which is marked with huge bolded letters "This library is no longer being maintained. Use at your own risk" on its README):

```
super(record, *(args << options), &block)
```

(notice the splat). Thus, if you have several options, they translate into several arguments, which `form_for` can't handle (notice the *absence* of a splat).

I suppose it just might work if you only have a single option; add an option, and I expect the above to happen.

Comment: I agree, i think it was the ClientSideValidations. I'm not using it anymore (made my own validation), and i copied the project and it magically began working again. Thanks